# Most frequently used design patterns in refactoring (my example)

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring

I've been doing quite a lot of refactoring of C++ and C# code recently, and found that 90% of the patterns I use are:

- Template method
- Factory
- Singleton

Are these generally the most commonly used patterns in refactoring or is it just me?
Can you share your refactoring experiences?

Answer (score 3):

We're using a lot of pub-sub, facade (oh man this is useful to make readable code), templating lately.  We hardly ever use Singleton, but that's because DI has taken care of all of that.